# Is every continuous function with a finite image f(I) constant?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let f: I $\to$R where I $\subset$ R be a continuous function such that f(I) is finite. Does it follow that f is a constant function?

I was asked to prove this, but ended up with finding a counter-example that left me confused;

Let I = [0,2$\pi$], f = sin(x). We know that the sine function is continuous, and clearly f(I) is finite since -1 $\leq$ sin(x) $\leq$ 1, yet f is not constant. What have I got wrong?

Comment: $f(I)$ is not finite: it has cardinality that of the continuum. In particular, $1/n$ is a distinct value taken by $f$ for every natural $n$.

Comment: I guess $I$ is a nondegenerate interval?

Comment: @user3482749 It seems as if I was confused of the interpretation of f(I) finite. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @TitoEliatron Doesn't really matter: it's true for degenerate intervals too (though not interesting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the notions of *finite* and *bounded*. Your example is one of a bounded function, but its image is not finite. In fact, the image of $\sin(x)$ on $[0,2\pi]$ is $[-1,1]$ wich has the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

As for the original question, the answer is yes because of the following fact: if $C \subset A$ is connceted, and $f : A \to B$ continuous, then $f(C)$ is connected. Here $A$ and $B$ can be topological spaces, but if you are not familiar with that, think for example of $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $B \subset \mathbb{R}^m$. In your case, since the interval $I$ is connected, so it should be $f(I)$. But we also know that $f(I)$ is finite, and finite (discrete) subspaces with more than one point are disconnected. Thus the only possible option is for $f(I)$ to contain a single element.

Comment: It is indeed the case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ were not constant, $f(I)$ has two (distinct) elements. Hence, Darboux property of continuous functions would say that $f$ would attain any intermediate value. So $f(I)$ would be infinite.

Comment: Probably the answer of @Guido A. would apply to a more general setting, but I think this one only uses basic calculus ideas.

Comment: Forgive my confusion, but doesn't Darboux property hold only for domains of the form [a,b], which is not necessarily the case?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that I is a nondegenerate ínterval.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that I is a nondegenerate  Ínter al. Butnthe argument is laso valid for any set with nonempty interior.